# how do I make sure a function does not return Null

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to parse XML from my Request in Soapui. And when I parse a Node without anything in it, logically the String is Null if the defining func() returns Null:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def request = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )    
def argumentString = request.getNodeValue("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body[1]/emm:RunApplication[1]/emm:argument[1]")
```

now I tried doing it like this:

```
try{argumentString.length()}catch(e){argumentsString = " "}
```

but this kills the Process after the correction, and doesn't quite give what I want. Can't use a Simple if(func()!=NULL) as i'm used to in Java? How can I do this? Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 2):

You *can* test for `null` values ...:
`argumentString = (argumentString != null) ? argumentString : " "`

BTW, with `argumentString?.length()`, `length()` will only be evaluated if `argumentString` isn't `null`.

Comment: Yeah that was the Error I was getting back. Thanks a lot for the Help

Comment: If that helped, what exactly did it (that it is possible to check for `null`, or the `?` "safe dereferencing" operator?) - Is your question solved? Thanks